# What will be going on if a pc boots with multiple disks all having bootable partitions?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, hard-drive, boot

I noticed if the instance on AWS EC2 has multiple disks which all have bootable partition, the instance would boot randomly from the disk without doing it in the order of the EBS volume id or disk device name. I was wondering is there any regularity in this situation, what will happen if a PC boots with multiple disks all having bootable partitions? Would the PC pick the disks to boot by following any type of rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think AWS EC2 User Guide's article [My Instance is Booting from the Wrong Volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-booting-from-wrong-volume.html) is an in-depth answer to your question. The emphasis is mine.

> In some situations, you may find that a volume other than the volume
>   attached to `/dev/xvda` or `/dev/sda` has become the root volume of your
>   instance. This can happen when you have attached the root volume of
>   another instance, or a volume created from the snapshot of a root
>   volume, to an instance with an existing root volume.
>
> This is due to how the initial ramdisk in Linux works. It will choose
>   the volume defined as `/` in the `/etc/fstab`, and in some distributions,
>   including Amazon Linux, **this is determined by the label attached to
>   the volume partition**.

And the fix in short:

> Use the `e2label` command to change the label of the volume to something
>   other than `/`.
>
> ```
> [ec2-user ~]$ sudo e2label /dev/xvdf1 old/
> ```

Comment: I think the OP is asking about a PC's behaviour. Great answer though.

Comment: Thanks. Is this because the bios on cloud computing environment   Couldn't be operated  to select a volume to boot from.  But I suppose the virtualized bios could have choosed a volume by default, couldn't it?

Comment: It's not really about which volume the BIOS is choosing, @Jepsenwan.  It's about which volume the bootloader on the first volume is choosing as the boot process proceeds.  You'd have the exact same issue on an ordinary PC even if the BIOS were booting the "first" hard drive but you had volumes with the same labels... it just becomes more likely in a cloud environment due to the relative simplicity of cloning and reattaching volumes, and the fact that the boot volumes of all machines tend to have a common ancestry.

Comment: AFAIK you can't access BIOS settings on AWS. I think this is why there isn't any boot order options and AWS lets the `init.rd` of first instance to handle this, as described in the article. Therefore, changing the label is THE solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks. and sorry, I just somehow removed the previous question ... As Michael described, even if we get the boot disk chosen in the BIOS setup. The bootloader on the first volume will choose the first hard driver with the label. Could you figure out if this happens in stage 1? For example, if I use MBR partition, the bootloader in stage 1 will be looking for a hard driver rather than a filesystem driver in stage 1.5 or a VBR in other partitions in the same disk in stage 2?

Comment: Oh... I see. The init ramdisk comes after the stage 2...